# Unity Dash empty

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and recently noticed that Dash home is empty with a message that no applications could be found. This has happened over the last few days and is not because of the upgrade to 16.04 which occurred months ago. If I start a search in Dash the apps are found. After opening the Dash, syslog reports the following:

```
04.12.16 14:50  steve64bit-EasyNote com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Home[1579]    (unity-scope-home:2454): unity-scope-home-WARNING **: scope.vala:669: Unable to search scope: timeout was reached

04.12.16 14:50  steve64bit-EasyNote-TSX66HR com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Home[1579]    (unity-scope-home:2454): libunity-WARNING **: unity-master-scope.vala:114: Unable to search scope: 'timeout was reached'
```

I have reinstalled unity-scope-home but the problem remains.

EDIT: SOLVED! The problem was Zeitgeist. I purged all zeitgeist installs (zeitgeist, zeitgeist-core, zeitgeist-datahub etc.) except for libzeitgeist-2.0-0 (too many dependencies including Nautilus). I then reinstalled them all and also reinstalled libzeitgeist-2.0-0. After a reboot the Dash is working again perfectly.

Comment: would you mind translating this to English?

Comment: @MarkYisri "Zeitüberschreitung wurde erreicht" simply means "timeout was reached". Edited the message.

Comment: It could be helpful to others if you post a real answer. I'm getting a similar error today which is spamming my journalctl: `Dec 19 13:28:34 alien com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Home[2392]: (unity-scope-home:19382): unity-scope-home-WARNING **: scope.vala:247: Failed to get list of remote scopes: Request failed with error 2`.

Comment: What is not "real" about the solution I posted four years ago?

Answer (score 1):

As told by the original asking person:

> The problem was Zeitgeist. I purged all zeitgeist installs (zeitgeist,
> zeitgeist-core, zeitgeist-datahub etc.) except for libzeitgeist-2.0-0
> (too many dependencies including Nautilus). I then reinstalled them
> all and also reinstalled libzeitgeist-2.0-0. After a reboot the Dash
> is working again perfectly.